# How to Export dynamic table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that users can manipulate the data inside the table whichever they select on my dropdown list. Now users has an option to export the displayed data in the table. When users click the Export nothing happens,  I am new in PHP and sorry for the english.

Below is my **index.php** and **excel.php**, can you tell what am i missing?

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $cmbDept = $_POST['cmbDept'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Campaign LIKE '" . $cmbDept . "'";
  $search_result = filterTable($query);
} else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2";
  $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

function filterTable($query) {
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bio_db");
  $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  return $filter_Result;
}
?>
```

**EXCEL.PHP**

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bio_db");
$output = '';
if (isset($_POST["export_excel"])) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Campaign LIKE '" . $cmbDept . "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $output .= '
      <table class="table bordered="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Userid</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Campaign</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Hoursworked</th>
          <th>Overtime</th>
        </tr>
        ';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $output .= '
        <tr>
          <td>' . $row["Userid"] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row["Name"] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row["Campaign"] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row["Date"] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row["Hoursworked"] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row["Overtime"] . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    header("Content-Type: application/xls");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");
    echo $output;
  }
}?>
```

HTML CODE in INDEX.PHP

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>Employee Logs</title>
<style>
        table,tr,th,td
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <h2 align="center">Time and Attendance Monitoring</h2>

    <center>

    <form method="GET" action="excel.php">

        <input type="submit" name="export_excel" class="btn btn-success" value="Export to Excel">
    </form>

    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <select id="cmbDept" name="cmbDept">
        <option value = '' selected="selected">Filter by Department</option>
            <option value = 'TKV'>TKV</option>
            <option value = 'NA'>NA</option>
            <option value = 'PURE-INC'>PURE INC</option>
            <option value = 'DUTY-FREE'>DUTY-FREE</option>
            <option value = 'HQL'>HQL</option>
            <option value = 'PRO-XPN'>PRO-XPN</option>
            <option value = 'Mate1'>Mate1</option>
            <option value = 'STUDENT-rUS'>STUDENT-rUS</option>
            <option value = 'COLLECTIONS'>COLLECTIONS</option>
            <option value = 'NTD'>NTD</option>
            <option value = 'DATA RESEARCHER'>DATA RESEARCHER</option>
            <option value = 'VA'>DATA RESEARCHER</option>

        </select>           
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"><br><br>

    </center>

    <table align="center" width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Userid</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Campaign</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Hoursworked</th>
            <th>Overtime</th>
        </tr>

    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Userid'];?></td>
            <td width="200"><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Campaign'];?></td>
            <td width="100" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Date'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Hoursworked'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Overtime'];?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endwhile;?>

        </table>

    //<?php 
    //  $cmbDept = $_GET['cmbDept'];
//  ?>
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: $cmbDept is undefined in excel.php

Comment: how should i define it?

Comment: are you using <a> tag for export?

Comment: can you display your html code

Comment: From Where `$cmbDept` coming into **EXCEL.php**?

Comment: @NanaPartykar, should i remove it? i thought i'm gonna used that for export

Comment: see the answer below

Comment: **WARNING:** You're open to [SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Consider [binding your parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML :

```
<form method="POST" action="excel.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmbDept" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['cmbDept']) ? $_POST['cmbDept'] : ''; ?>"> 
    <input type="submit" name="export_excel" class="btn btn-success" value="Export to Excel">
</form>
```

Excel.php

```
if (isset($_POST["export_excel"])) {
  $cmbDept = $_POST['cmbDept'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Campaign LIKE '" . $cmbDept . "'";
```

Comment: And, from where you got this line `<input type="hidden" name="cmbDept" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['cmbDept']) ? $_POST['cmbDept'] : ''; ?>">`??

Comment: he has both html and php code in same file index.php

Comment: use post method in export_excel

Comment: @Rijin I tried your code, it runs perfect! but it has no data inside the excel? but it has header in all column, it shows error arround here "while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))"

Answer (score 1):

***Changes Need To Be Do:***

**1)** Change in **excel.php**

`if (isset($_POST["export_excel"])) {`

To

`if (isset($_GET["export_excel"])) {`

as, `method="GET"` is present in `<form></form>`

**2)** No, `$cmbDept` present in `excel.php`. So, you need to pass inside the form in hidden form.

Like,

```
<form method="GET" action="excel.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmbDept" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['cmbDept']) ? $_POST['cmbDept'] : ''; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="export_excel" class="btn btn-success" value="Export to Excel">
</form>
```

**3)** Get value of `$cmbDept` using GET as `<form>` is having `method='GET'`.

***UPDATED CODE***

**index.php**

```
<form method="GET" action="excel.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmbDept" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['cmbDept']) ? $_POST['cmbDept'] : ''; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="export_excel" class="btn btn-success" value="Export to Excel">
</form>
```

**excel.php**

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bio_db");

if (isset($_GET["export_excel"])) {

  $cmbDept = $_GET['cmbDept'];

  header("Content-Type: application/xls");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");

  $sep = "\t"; 

  $sql = "SELECT `Userid`,`Name`,`Campaign`,`Date`,`Hoursworked`,`Overtime` FROM daily_data2 WHERE Campaign LIKE '" . $cmbDept . "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

  //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
  while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
      echo $property->name.$sep;
  }
  print("\n");
  //end of printing column names

  //start while loop to get data
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM))
  {
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
  }
}
?>
```

These suggestions will solve all your existing problem.

Comment: Great your awesome!

Comment: actually it does not but you explain well, you missed in method="POST" which Rijin used, so i will give him the answer, thanks for the reply.

Comment: "*..actually it does not..*" It's Not Possible That It Will Not Work. No Problem @Seryu. *Enjoy Coding.*